# Retrieve CSS value, not inline-style value

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, can I retrieve the CSS values of an element without taking account of its inline style?
**example:**

```
body { font-size: 15px; }

<body style="font-size: 20px;">
```

Is there a way I can retrieve "15px" and not "20px"?

Comment: Ditch the `style` attribute, get computed style, then add the style attribute back?

Comment: @nrabinowitz: That's how I'd do it, yeah.

Comment: I agree with @nrabinowitz. Code snippet coming right up!

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Suggest posting that as an answer (with an example).

Comment: But if there is CSS transition on the property, wouldn't I risk seeing a glitch by adding and removing the inline-style?

Comment: @SimonArnold, I dont think there will be a glitch because were talking milliseconds here.

Comment: @SimonArnold: You'd have to try it, if you're using transitions that are affected by the inline style, it could well have an impact.

Comment: Sorry, should have posted an answer - I didn't have time to work up a full example, so I just threw out the suggestion in a comment. Glad it worked out :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course! Just get rid of the `style` attribute, use `getComputedStyle()`, and add the `style` attribute back:

```js
//Get the body's style attribute:
var bodyStyle = document.body.getAttribute("style");
//Now, get rid of it:
document.body.removeAttribute("style");
//Now use getComputedStyle() to compute the font size of the body and output it to the screen:
document.write( getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize );
//Now add the style attribute back:
document.body.setAttribute("style", bodyStyle);
```

```css
body { font-size: 15px; }
```

```html
<body style="font-size: 20px;">
</body>
```

Comment: I'd've given nrabinowitz a bit more time to post his comment as an answer, or at least make the answer a CW. (Frustrating when people post answers as comments, but I always CW when I decide to repost it as an answer.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh...I was already working on the code snippet before that comment was posted. It's just that I saw a new comment and responded so people would know I was making a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
   console.log (a[0].attributes.style);  // returns the current inline style
   a[0].setAttribute('style','font-size : 15px'); // change it as required
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: thanks @Simon for your comment, revisiting the question, I see that I missed the point. Thanks :-)